# Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset. for SS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web

I have a website that was devloped using ASP.NET MVC and hosted in the IIS with source and working properly.

Today i have hosted the website in production environment in another location in the same server and configured the IIS. While accessing the HTTPS page i have faced the below problem.

"Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset. for SSL"

Is we need to configure the IIS anything special to resolve this ?

Thanks,
Velusamy

Comment: Alos, when try to connect through the server . I have faced the below problem.

    *   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
          moments.

    *   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
          connection.

    *   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
          that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: Are you using any host-headers for your site?

Comment: How did you set up SSL ?

Comment: Consider adding more information to your question.  For example, you mention the website is hosted multiple times on the same server -- assuming you mean Production and a Stage or Dev environment.  Please elaborate the differences and the current settings.

Comment: The error message is not a typical one from IIS itself. So you might show a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the maxRequest .net issue. Try adding the following to the `appSettings` of your `web.config` file.

`<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="9999" />`

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to your ISP. I wrote a quick blog post about it -

http://blog.agmon.com/2013/07/05/solving-error-101-neterr_connection_reset-the-connection-was-reset/

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as I was messing around with other settings in IIS. Somehow in my HTTPS bindings for the site, the self-signed security certificate was removed (when editing the binding, SSL Certificate was "Not Specified".

All I did was reselect the correct certificate and it fixed the problem. I would check that this hasn't happened to you first.

Answer (score 0):

You can test  https Connect via Web proxy

1. Install / execute Fiddler.  (  https://www.telerik.com/fiddler  )
2. Link to the problem page with the Internet browser.

If the corresponding connection is possible,
It is seen in the problem of the user's Internet browser and Server's "Cipher suite".

Server's Cipher Suites and SSL/TLS Version confirmation
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

Client's(Internet browser) Cipher Suites and SSL/TLS Version confirmation
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html

1. One or more "Cipher Suites" must be the same. .
2. check the SSL and TLS version you support.

If the same "Cipher Suites" does not exist
Take IIS Crypto 2.0 down. 
https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Download/

After executing the program, press "Best Practices" button to set.
Please restart the test after rebooting.

http://dev.d-0-b.kr/22
Reference site. (Korean)